# Do we have expiration for google cloud data fusion drafts

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

Anyone is aware whether CDAP drafts saved has any expiry , I have created few drafts in one of the cloud data fusion instance and the same instance is being used by other folks . But after like 2-3 days when I tried to retrieve the draft , found it to be missing and no one deleted that for sure. Just wondering whether there is an  expiration attached to each draft we create in CDAP?

Comment: Psen: The pipeline drafts don't have an expiry. They are stored in the user store and if the instance is shared between several users then it is most likely one of the usages must have deleted the drafts.

Comment: No even if no one is using , I have seen it is getting deleted. Do you have any pointer from where I can find the saved drafts from user store ?

Comment: As @Ajai said there is not expiry date for pipeline drafts within DataStudio. You can find your drafts at: *Open Data Studio console > Click on the icon at the top left corner > (Under Pipeline) click on List > Then you will see Deployed and Drafts ( click on Drafts)*.

Comment: That i know from where to see the list of pipelines (deployed as well as drafts) , looking for any log or internal storage from where I get to see how it got deleted .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no expiry attached to drafts. However there is a known issue with saving drafts when multiple users are using the same instance and try saving a draft at the same time.

Unfortunately the only way to guarantee that your draft will not be lost is to either deploy the pipeline or export the pipeline JSON and save it locally as a backup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have a reference handy about the known issue?

Comment: @Psen [here's](https://issuetracker.google.com/179596844) a public issue that tracks this.

Comment: @Psen to clarify, [this](https://cdap.atlassian.net/browse/CDAP-17102) is the known issue I was referring to. This issue has been fixed in the 6.3.0 version of CDAP. The issue linked by milia is a bug that was discovered in 6.3.0 that would lead to drafts not being visible if they were created outside of the "default" namespace. This has been fixed and will be part of the upcoming 6.4.0 release.